# dynamic dag creation based on dependencies from table

Tags: airflow

i am reading from table which contains the tasks to be executed and i am also storing the dependencies in the same table. i am reading the table into a pandas data frame.

[image: here's the table which i read into the pandas dataframe]

my task 3 is dependent on task 1 & task 2 while task 4 is dependent on task 3 for completion.

```html
for index, row in odf.iterrows():

 dag_id = row["DAG_ID"]
 task_id = row["TASK_ID"]
 task_name = row["TASK_NAME"]
 script_name = row["SCRIPT_NAME"]
 if row["DEPENDENT_ID"] is not None:
   dependents = row["DEPENDENT_ID"].split('|')
   print(dependents)

   t1 = OracleOperator(task_id=task_name,
                   oracle_conn_id='oracle_con',
                   sql='Begin %s; end;' % script_name, dag=dag)

   for d in dependents:

     for index, row in odf[odf["TASK_ID"] == int(d)].iterrows():
          t2 =  OracleOperator(task_id=row["TASK_NAME"],
                                       oracle_conn_id='oracle_con',
                                       sql= 'Begin %s; end;' %script_name,dag = dag)
          t1.set_upstream(t2)
```

but my output is not able coming as expected and below is what i see.
[image: i know i am doing something wrong in the loop]

i know that i could do something like this.

```html
t1 = OracleOperator(task_id='run_proc_ihn_reference_raw',
                                       oracle_conn_id='oracle_con',
                                       sql= 'Begin proc.task1; end;',dag = dag)

t2 = OracleOperator(task_id='run_proc_aim_codelist_raw',
                                       oracle_conn_id='oracle_con',
                                       sql= 'Begin proc.task2; end;',dag = dag)

t3 = OracleOperator(task_id='run_proc_decline_reason_dim_build',
                                       oracle_conn_id='oracle_con',
                                       sql= 'Begin proc.task3; end;',dag = dag)

t4 = OracleOperator(task_id='run_proc_decline_reason_dim_load',
                                       oracle_conn_id='oracle_con',
                                       sql= 'Begin proc.task4; end;',dag = dag)

(t1,t2) >> t3 >> t4
```

but i might have more than 100 procedures and so looking for dag to be created with dependencies using above method.

need help for the same. Thank you

Comment: What's the purpose of reading a source to create the process?

Comment: the purpose is to dynamically create the dag. the procedure names which needs to be executed are stored in table along with the dependencies. all i am trying to do is create a dag using the data from table

Comment: You can't have dynamic processes in Airflow. I'd also recommend _not_ going down this path, it makes it much harder to understand and increases processing load.

Comment: is there any other way where i can automatically retrieve the for given task the dependencies for it instead of having to write 50 tasks and calling either the upstream or downstream ?? i am not creating the dags dynamically. rather i am trying to retrieve or create the dependencies dynamically.

Comment: suggested read [this](https://www.astronomer.io/guides/dynamically-generating-dags/) and then [some more](https://www.google.com/search?q=airflow+dynamic+generate+tasks+from+db)

Comment: I think it's best to recall that you've the entirety of the Python standard library at your disposal as well, things such as `map`, `functools.partial` etc. I'll write up an answer with some suggestions for dealing with repetitive/large amounts of tasks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When dealing with large numbers of tasks involving complicated dependencies I find that I usually end up repeating quite a bit of "task boilerplate", as you've shown in your example.

In these situations I like to let Python do the "heavy lifting" in creating the tasks and wiring them up:

```py
default_args = {
    "oracle_conn_id": "oracle_con"
}

task_dict = {
    "ihn_reference_raw":        {"proc": "task1"},
    "aim_codelist_raw":         {"proc": "task2"},
    "decline_reason_dim_build": {"proc": "task3", 
                                 "upstream": ["ihn_reference_raw", 
                                              "aim_codelist_raw"]},
    "decline_reason_dim_load":  {"proc": "task4", 
                                 "upstream": ["decline_reason_dim_build"]}
}

...

with DAG(
    ..., 
    default_args=default_args
) as dag:

    # Iterate the details to create the tasks
    for task_id, details in task_dict.items():
        OracleOperator(task_id=f"run_proc_{task_id}",
                       sql=f"BEGIN {details['proc']}; END;")

    # Iterate a second time to "wire up" the upstream tasks.
    for task_id, details in task_dict.items():
        if task_up := details.get("upstream"):
            dag.get_task(f"run_proc_{task_id}").set_upstream(task_up)
```

(I've left out quite a bit for brevity, but the idea is there)

The key is to find the portions of your process that are repetitive, store the things that are unique to each task (*in our `task_dict` in this example*) and then loop to build.

Comment: thank you. i tried creating an example on your idea though i'm constantly getting an error "airflow.exceptions.AirflowExceptioin: relationships can only be set between operators; received str".                                                                                                                        
 for task_id, details in task_dict.items():
    if details.get("upstream") is not None:
        for item in details.get("upstream"):
            item = item.replace("'", "")
            dag.get_task(f"{task_id}").set_upstream(f"{item}")

Comment: No issues. seems i had to use dag.get_task inside in set_upstream too. dag.get_task(f"{details['task_name']}").set_upstream(dag.get_task(item)). once again thanks for your help joebeeson.

Comment: @user1672315 I'm glad to hear it worked out for you

Comment: I am struggling with this solution. My setup is a bit different in that I have a task group in the dag and when I try this..the generation of the tasks work great, but when I try to get_task using the task_id I get an errorr saying the task {task_id} was not found.